# Why does android limit vm memory size to an arbitrary 24 or 32 MB?

Tags: android, memory-management

I created a top down game in which your character move around a level. The level is essentially a 1600x2400 png. I cannot load that png into memory so I have to use BitmapRegionDecoder to load it in chunks as the player moves around the level. Of course this sucks and possibly leads to stuttering. I thought of loading the next chunk in a background thread but that meant that I had two chunks in memory: the current one and the next one, which would lead to an OutOfMemoryException.

Now all devices have at least 512 MB or RAM so why do we still have that stupid limit on vm ram?? It is despotic of Google to tell us how much ram we should use! Let us decide! Now I have to eat a lot more cpu cycles just because I can't load the whole thing into RAM, not to mention the worse performance that I get with this BitmapRegionDecoder!

Any ideas why Google does this and when will it end? What is the logical argument behind that decision?

Answer (score 2):

a) 512MB RAM does not mean that your app can use that much. The free memory is still pretty limited. So I guess it will never end. The amount the VM gets will probably increase but if you want to stay compatible then you have to code efficiently. (e.g. split images and not load the data from a giant image)

b) You can use JNI / NDK / C and manage the memory yourself, there is no limit for native code.

Comment: I guess the idea about splitting images is not that good at all. This is due to different screen resolution of different devices. I'm pretty sure that author tries to make the game look similar on different devices which means if device has bigger screen resolution than user will see more instead of stretched and blured small piece. So its a real dilemma decode region and get Out Of Memory or split by pieces and get low quality looking product in some cases. And this AOS VM's memory limitation really sucks especially nowadays!

Comment: Splitting images into tiles is a good idea if you have arbitrarily large images like google maps for example. You obviously need to do a whole lot more to display it as if it was one image but you gain total independence of image size. And you can see from that example that you don't have blurry images if you do it correctly. It's just not as easy as loading a single image.

Comment: agree, I was keeping that in mind, I mean a lot of more work to do. At the other side a lot of more work to do == more chance to get lagging/stuttering etc.